# Javascript DateFormat for different timezones

Tags: javascript

I'm a Java developer and I'm used to the SimpleDateFormat class that allows me to format any date to any format by settings a timezone.

```
Date date = new Date();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(date)); // Prints date in Los Angeles

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(date)); // Prints same date in Chicago
```

SimpleDateFormat is a pretty neat solution in Java but unfortunately I can't find any similar alternative in Javascript.

I'm extending the Date prototype in **Javascript** to do exactly the same. I have dates in Unix format but I want to format them in different timezones.

```
Date.prototype.format = function(format, timezone) {
    // Now what?
    return formattedDate;
}
```

I'm looking for a neat way to do this rather than a hack.

Thanks

Comment: There's no easy way to do this. JavaScript has little or no support for timezones. In a calendar app I had built, I had more than a few pages of code to handle dates and timezones, including a large XML file that had to be downloaded from the server that contained the cities and their corresponding zones - AND their daylight savings time rules.

Comment: Let's say I provide the GMT Raw Offset, would that make it any easier?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a way to format for time zones.

```
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US', {timeZone: 'America/Denver'}))
// 11/13/2018
console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {timeZone: 'America/Denver'}))
// 2:30:54 PM
console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {timeZone: 'America/New_York'}))
// 4:31:26 PM
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString

Answer (score 3):

The ISO Extended format for common date is YYYY-MM-DD, and for time is hh:mm:ss. Either format can be understood, unambiguously, worldwide.

See also:
http://jibbering.com/faq/#dates

Answer (score 1):

If you're just passing the raw TZ there's nothing really complicated about adjusting the hours.
My example below is of course abbreviated. Yours may get quite long depending on how many patterns you'd handle.

```
Date.prototype.format = function(format, tzAdjust) {
    // adjust timezone
    this.setHours(this.getHours()+tzAdjust)
    // pad zero helper - return "09" or "12"
    var two = function(s){ return s+"".length==1 ? "0"+s : s+""; }
    // replace patterns with date numbers
    return format.replace(/dd|MM|yyyy|hh|mm|ss/g, function(pattern){
        switch(pattern){
            case "d" : return this.getDate();
            case "dd" : return two(this.getDate());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is not a very clean solution. Because let's say you want to format the same date twice, it will be adjusted twice.

On the other hand, getHours returns the hour on the user's timezone, adding the raw offset is not enough, you need to consider the user's timezone as well (getTimezoneOffset()).

Anyway, by using setHours, you'll be changing the date which is a wrong way to handle dates.

Comment: Furthermore, not all timezone offsets are in increments of 1 hour.

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to (ever so slightly) improve upon mwilcox's suggestion:

```
Date.prototype.format = function(format, tzAdjust) {

    // get/setup a per-date-instance tzDate object store
    var tzCache = this.__tzCache = this.__tzCache || (this.__tzCache = {});

    // fetch pre-defined date from cache 
    var tzDate = tzCache[tzAdjust];
    if ( !tzDate )
    {
      // on miss - then create a new tzDate and cache it
      tzDate = tzCache[tzAdjust] = new Date( this );
      // adjust by tzAdjust (assuming it's in minutes 
      // to handle those weird half-hour TZs :) 
      tzDate.setUTCMinutes( tzDate.getUTCMinutes()+tzAdjust );
    }

    return format.replace(/dd|MM|yyyy|hh|mm|ss/g, function(pattern){
               // replace each format tokens with a value 
               // based on tzDate's corresponding UTC property
             });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are clearly asking two questions in one, formatting and time zone. They need to be addressed separately. Formatting is pretty trivial, if none of the other answers will do for that you will have to be more specific.

As for the time and time zone, if you have your server inject the UTC time, preferably as UNIX time in milliseconds, into the JavaScript, you can compare that to the time on the client machine, and thus work out how far from UTC the client is. Then you can calculate the time of any time zone you want.

Edit: I actually didn't know JavaScript also had built in UTC time until I checked on the internet, neat.

In any case, I suppose this is want you want:

```
Date.prototype.format=function(format,timezone){
    var obj=new Date(this.getTime()+this.getTimezoneOffset()*60000+timezone*3600000);
    var two=function(s){
        return s<10?"0"+s:s+"";
    }
    return format.replace(/dd|MM|yyyy|hh|mm|ss/g, function(pattern){
        switch(pattern){
            case "dd" : return two(obj.getDate());
            case "MM" : return two(obj.getMonth()+1);
            case "yyyy" : return obj.getFullYear();
            case "hh" : return two(obj.getHours());
            case "mm" : return two(obj.getMinutes());
            case "ss" : return two(obj.getSeconds());
        }
    });
}
```

You can add in more patterns if you need.

Comment: eBusiness, I'm not asking two questions in one. In many programming languages, the Date object does not change with the timezone, it's the way it's displayed that changes. The date NOW is the same everywhere in the world but it's displayed differently.

If you look at my Java Example, notice how I'm displaying the same Date object using two different Date Formats.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but since I found it:

As mentioned, there's nothing reasonable built-in.

As for libs, there is [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) for [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Here is a JSfiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kunycrkb/

The same code inline:

```
var m = moment("2014-06-01T13:05:00Z");
var f = "HH:mm z";

$("#results").text(m.tz("UTC").format(f) + " is " + m.tz("EST").format(f) +  "!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't write your own stuff; just get datejs: http://www.datejs.com/

You can figure out what the timezone offset is set to in the execution environment like this:

```
var local = new Date();
var utc = Date.UTC(local.getFullYear(), local.getMonth(), local.getDate(), local.getHours(), local.getMinutes(), local.getSeconds(), local.getMilliseconds());
var tz = (utc - local.getTime()) / (60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: The goal is to handle timezones, DateJS doesn't seem to do so.

Comment: Alpha release in 2007 and no activity since.

Answer (score 0):

Since my requirement was a typescript solution but I stumbled here I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2741742/1660759) to write my typescript function.

Based on answer above, a function in typescript which converts a timestamp or a date object into a formatted local time string.

```
const formatDateString = (date_or_ts:Date|number):string=>{
    let obj:Date;

    if(typeof date_or_ts === "number"){
        obj = new Date(date_or_ts*1000);
        // obj=new Date(obj.getTime()+obj.getTimezoneOffset()*60000+timezone*3600000);
    }else{
        obj = date_or_ts;
    }
    const format = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss";
    let two=function(s:number){
        return s<10?"0"+s:s+"";
    }
    return format.replace(/dd|MM|yyyy|hh|mm|ss/g, function(pattern){
        const months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
        switch(pattern){
            case "dd" : return two(obj.getDate()).toString();
            case "MM" : return months[obj.getMonth()];
            case "yyyy" : return obj.getFullYear().toString();
            case "hh" : return two(obj.getHours()).toString();
            case "mm" : return two(obj.getMinutes()).toString();
            case "ss" : return two(obj.getSeconds()).toString();
            default: return "";
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a JavaScript port of PHP's date function:

e.g.

```js
console.log( new Date("2023-01-01").return("M d Y") )
```

returns `"JAN 01 2023"`

```js
console.log ( new Date("1980-01-01").return("\\\\D\\\\av\\\\i\\\\d \\\\w\\\\a\\\\s bor\\\\n o\\\\n M d Y \\\\a\\\\n\\\\d \\\\here'\\\\s t\\\\he e\\\\s\\\\c\\\\ape \\\\c\\\\h\\\\ar \\\\\\")
```

returns `"David was born on JAN 01 1980 and here's the escape char \\"`

```
if (!Date.prototype.return) {
    Date.prototype.return = function (format) {
        if (isNaN(this.valueOf()) || !this.valueOf()) { return null; }
        let days        = ["SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED", "THR", "FRI", "SAT"];
        let months      = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"];
        let newDate     = new Date(this.getTime() + this.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
        let month       = newDate.getMonth();
        let weekDay     = newDate.getDay();
        let day         = newDate.getDate();
        let year        = newDate.getFullYear();
        let hour        = newDate.getHours();
        let minute      = newDate.getMinutes();
        let second      = newDate.getSeconds();
        let string      = [];
        let escapeNext  = false;
        for (const character of format) {
            if (escapeNext) {
                string.push(character);
                escapeNext = false;
            } else if (character === "\\") {
                escapeNext = true;
            } else {
                switch (character) {
                    case "a": string.push(hour < 12 ? "AM" : "PM");             break;
                    case "c": string.push(newDate.toISOString());               break;
                    case "d": string.push(String("0" + day).slice(-2));         break;
                    case "D": string.push(days[weekDay]);                       break;
                    case "F": string.push(months[month]);                       break;
                    case "g": let h = hour === 0 ? 12 : hour;                   
                              string.push(h > 12 ? h - 12 : h);                 
                              break;                                            
                    case "h": h = hour === 0 ? 12 : hour;                       
                              h = h > 12 ? h - 12 : h;                          
                              string.push(String("0" + h).slice(-2));           
                              break;                                            
                    case "H": string.push(String("0" + hour).slice(-2));        break;
                    case "i": string.push(String("0" + minute).slice(-2));      break;
                    case "j": string.push(day);                                 break;
                    case "l": string.push(days[weekDay]);                       break;
                    case "m": string.push(String("0" + (month + 1)).slice(-2)); break;
                    case "M": string.push(months[month].substring(0, 3));       break;
                    case "n": string.push(month + 1);                           break;
                    case "s": string.push(String("0" + second).slice(-2));      break;
                    case "w": string.push(weekDay);                             break;
                    case "y": string.push(year.toString().slice(-2));           break;
                    case "Y": string.push(year);                                break;
                    default : string.push(character);
                }
            }
        }
        return string.join("");
    };
}
```