# how to modify this javascript time function to show hours less than ten as: 0x

Tags: php, javascript, time

```
//Live Javascript Server Time
function getthedate(){
    var mydate=new Date()
    var hours=mydate.getHours()
    var minutes=mydate.getMinutes()
    var seconds=mydate.getSeconds()
    var dn="AM"
        if (hours>=12)
        dn="PM"
        if (hours>12){
        hours=hours-12
        }
        if (hours==0)
        hours=12
        if (minutes<=9)
        minutes="0"+minutes
        if (seconds<=9)
        seconds="0"+seconds

    var cdate="<strong><font color='b9b9b9' size='1'> "+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds+" "+dn+"</font></strong>"
    if (document.all)
    document.all.clock.innerHTML=cdate
    else if (document.getElementById)
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML=cdate
    else
    document.write(cdate)
    }
if (!document.all&&!document.getElementById)
getthedate()
function live_servertime(){
if (document.all||document.getElementById)
setInterval("getthedate()",1000)
}
```

Does this display the **live SERVER time**? If not, any ideas how to achieve this?
Also I'm stumped on how to modify it to put a zero in front of hours that are less than ten?

Comment: You managed to put a 0 on the minutes and seconds, but you’re stumped with the hours? Are you sure you wrote this code?

Comment: this was part of an open source code I found.  I'm not nearly as good at programming in javascript as I am in .php, have to rely on example scripts and tutorials when i use javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you understand how the `minutes`  and `seconds` get the leading zero, it should be pretty obvious.

```
    if (hours==0)
    hours=12
    if (hours <= 9)          // <--
       hours = "0" + hours;  // <--
    if (minutes<=9)
    minutes="0"+minutes
    if (seconds<=9)
    seconds="0"+seconds
```

and no, `new Date()` just gets the time from the client.

Comment: owh.   How would i integrate the server time in this script?

Comment: @Callum: Why you need *live* server time?

Comment: I want it to display the live server time on the website just for aesthetic and user purposes?

Comment: @Callum: It waste quite a lot of bandwidth though. And because of network latency it the server time may be already outdated once it reaches the client.

Comment: oh okay, is it worth doing?

Or can i take user time zone and match that to my server time zone?

Comment: like, ammend the javascript if timezones are not equal?

Comment: @Callum: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613511/javascript-dateformat-for-different-timezones.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: look at how minutes and seconds get a leading zero.

```
    if (minutes<=9)
    minutes="0"+minutes
```

Comment: if (hours>12){
hours=hours-12
hours="0"+hours
}

the zero issue is fixed,  but what about server time?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn’t display the *server* time. I can’t, because it runs entirely on the client (browser) and doesn’t communicate with the server.

To put a 0 in front of the single-digits hours, just do the same that you’re already doing with the minutes and secconds:

```
if (hours <= 9)
    hours = "0" + hours;
```