# Make Highchart use a specific targeted time zone

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts, timezone

I'm using highchart to display data along a time x axis. The data are relative to a specific location on the globe so I need to make HightChart display the time of this location. Which is neither UTC nor the local browser time zone.

I already seen the UTC setting, to make use of UTC or browser's local time :

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: { 
        useUTC: true
    }
});
```

And I already think of applying a delay according to my targeted time zone in the label formatter. but it's slightly more complicated : how to manage manually the summer / winter time switch in any targeted country etc

Maybe if there is a way to set the time zone in a javascript date object to use a `getLocalString()` with a specific time zone ?  :/

Any idea on how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution is to use UTC in Highcharts, then if you know what time-zone you want to display you know already offset. Then simply in all formatters (xAxis, tooltip, etc.) add offset to display proper date.

Comment: That what I did so far. unfortunatly its not enough :  when the highchart component use the browser's local timezone, it manages properly the DST / winter time switch according to the browser's country. This solution does not : there is a one hour delay when the date is in DST. If highchart manages well the browser's time zone for any country. Why don't add the possibility to set a third party timezone ?

Comment: Because Javascript doesn't support for it's own (as far as I know). Regarding DST you can always try to check if date is +/- 1hours. Another possible solution is to use categories.

Comment: I guess your right on the javascript support for third party time zones : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613511/javascript-dateformat-for-different-timezones. I'll probably have to get the information about DST from my server  to apply a 1hour delay in my formatters...   thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

If it is neither UTC now local browser time zone then just supply a time stamp as part of your series, either as a second array for the x-axis label or `pointStart` in conjunction with `pointInterval` series properties if your data is regularly spaced.

In either case it seems like you will need to do some server-side pre-processing in order to get the time zone right.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved by setting  **useUTC: false** and then had the server send timestamps for the desired timezone.   In my case, server sends "eastern time" data and all charts show eastern time on x axis, however client is not in eastern time.

Comment: Could you share some code? this does not work for me, but it shouldn´t according to the Highcharts reference..

Answer (score 0):

To Make Highchart use a specific targeted time zone you can specify the timezone for the chart.
Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.timezone
To know How to use this timezone option in ReactJs, refer this URL
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8661