# Convert year string into date

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to convert year string into a date type like in the following example:

```
var date = new Date('1999');
console.log(date); // result -> Thu Dec 31 1998 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

The problem is with time zone. Because the string is not properly formated and it is treated as UTC time zone.

How to convert year string properly and **treat as** **local time**?

I know that it will work if I append day and month like this `'01/01/' + '1999'` but is it possible some other solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613511/javascript-dateformat-for-different-timezones

Comment: `new Date(1999, 0)` should do. Pass it as year+month parameters, not a string to be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize a date with an empty value to avoid problems with default properties.

```
var date = new Date("");
date.setYear(1999);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first create a new Date object with the current timezone, then get your timezone offset and then subtract it from it.

> The getTimezoneOffset() method returns the time zone difference, in
>   minutes, from current locale (host system settings) to UTC.

The following should work:

```
var x = new Date().getTime() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
var y = new Date(x);
console.log(y);
```

You can also try it online on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g49bntrn/).

Answer (score 0):

You should always declare any date variables using UTC explicitly, then convert them when you need to. Declare the date in UTC first then convert it to a string. So I think you need:

```
var date = new Date('1999-01-01 08:00:00 UTC');
console.log(date.toString());
```