# Does any documentation exist to show the "default" Intl.DateTimeFormat options for a specific locale in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, locale

For example, if I'm using "en-US" as the locale parameter, is there any documentation that says "this is what `options.dateStyle = 'full'`" will display as?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript DateFormat for different timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613511/javascript-dateformat-for-different-timezones)

Comment: I don't think so. I'm looking for the formats associated with locales. e.g. "en-US" would be "August 17, 1985", "en-GB" would be "17 August 1985".